# How to copy YouTube's app navigation logic

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I want to implement in my app navigation logic like in Youtube app. (BottomNavigationView + Fragment management). I want this, because these fragments are heavy, so I want them to be lazy initialized and then stored in backstack, I feel like YouTube is doing it this way. I have implemented BottomNagivationView but I have problems with Fragment Management.

My code:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnTabSelectedListener { position, _ -> 
    setFragment(OnlinePageFragment.Page.values()[position])
}
```

where Pages is enum

```
enum class Page(index: Int, val klass: Class<*>) {
        ONE(0, OnePageFragment::class.java),
        TWO(1, TwoPageFragment::class.java),
        THREE(2, ThreePageFragment::class.java)
    }
```

and here is my setFragment function

```
fun setFragment(page: OnlinePageFragment.Page) {
    var fragment: Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(page.klass.name)
    val tag = page.klass.name

    if (fragment == null)
        fragment = OnlinePageFragment.newInstance(page, null)

    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    with(ft) {
        replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tag)
        addToBackStack(tag)
        commit()
    }

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 1) finish()
    else super.onBackPressed()
}
```

And it's working, but not as good as YouTube app. YouTube app has some magic behaviour i.e. it keeps only one transaction per each fragment, while my app allows to create "infinite" backstack of transactions. Do you have any ideas how it works in YouTube app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [san's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553927/how-to-copy-youtubes-app-navigation-logic/51117293#51117293) was showing fragments as expected, but has some bugs that call onCreateView on HomeFragment twice each time the fragment is changed. Additionally changing page is instantiating new fragment each time the page is changed.
So I took the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45542613/3858030) and modified my `setPage` and it's working great.

Here is how:

```
private void setPage(Page page) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    String tag = page.name();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // detach everything
    for (Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments()) {
        transaction.detach(fragment);
    }

    // Retrieve fragment instance, if it was already created
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null) { // If not, crate new instance and add it
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) page.clazz.newInstance();
            transaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment, tag);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else { // otherwise just attach it
        transaction.attach(fragment);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

onBackPressed implementation

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Page.HOME.name()).isDetached()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using view pager you can manage it.
I have implemented Please check this. https://github.com/sandeshsk/BackStackFragmentRedirectsToHome

Please update if there is any issue.

This is a method which assigns fragment

```
public void addFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                               Fragment fragment,
                               int containerId,boolean isFromHome){

    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(isFromHome){
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId,fragment);
    }else{
        fragmentTransaction.add(new HomeFragment(),"Home");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Home");
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId,fragment).commit();

}
```

This is your navigation item listener

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
               if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), new HomeFragment(), R.id.frame, true);
                }else{
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),new DashboardFragment(),R.id.frame,false);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),new NotificationFragment(),R.id.frame,false);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_setting:
                addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),new SettingFragment(),R.id.frame,false);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

onBackPressed method

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer since it's showing the fragments as expected. But there is problem. Every time I switch fragment HomeFragment is created twice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way here is to use `ViewPager` to store root fragments. Navigation bar will change pages of `ViewPager`.

Root fragments will store content fragments inside their `ChildFragmentManagers`and implement logic of navigation between content fragments.

Also you will need to implement logic of delegation backpress events from activity to root fragments, to perform navigation in their backstack.

**UPD #1**
Make sure, that root fragments are not destroyed inside ViewPager, use [setOffscreenPageLimit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

**UPD #2** 
If you don't want to use ViewPager, you can use code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45542613/3858030)  to manage root fragments.

Comment: ViewPager is my current implementation, and I wanted to change it since It's too heavy to load 3 fragments at once.

Comment: @StachuBarański if it's too heavy to load 3 fragments at start at first load only the first one and others populate with data if user swipes to see them.

Comment: @hardartcore I can't do that since ViewPager need to load all 3 fragments, so they are visible during swiping.

Comment: @StachuBarański you can do it, just listen to `setUserVisibleHint(boolean b)`, and trigger content loading when b is true (and it is not loaded or loading, or in some other conditions)

Comment: Ok, good to know then :) Anyway, I chosed the managing root fragments and it's working great (Fragment is created only once, onCreateView is called only once and everything is lazy initialized). See the accepted answer.